# CollectionConverters always return the original source object?

Tags: scala, performance, wrapper, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

[`CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) API states

> In all cases, converting from a source type to a target type and back
>   again will return the original source object.

This does not seem to be always true. For example, in the following case it is indeed [true](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QlEDbzSWThCIjGpmsWfgNA)

```
val orig = ListBuffer(1,2,3)
assert(orig.asJava.asScala eq orig)   // OK
```

however [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Mm8UJh7SQQ6EVENjktUagw) the assertion fails

```
val orig = ListBuffer(1,2,3).asJava
assert(orig.asScala.asJava eq orig)   // Boom!
```

Changing to a `List` instead of `ListBuffer` the assertion passes

```
val orig = List(1,2,3).asJava
assert(orig.asScala.asJava eq orig)   // OK
```

Does the middle case mean a copy was made? If so, what are the precise rules on when is a copy made hence there being a performance hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`asJava` and `asScala` never copy entire collections, but they do instantiate wrappers.

After `val orig = ListBuffer(1,2,3).asJava`, `orig` is a wrapper, an instance of class `scala.collection.convert.JavaCollectionWrappers$MutableBufferWrapper`.

After the next `.asScala`, you get the original `ListBuffer` back.

Now you call `.asJava` again. At this point, there is no other possible outcome than for a new wrapper to be instantiated, not (as you discovered) `eq` to the previous wrapper.

The guarantee that you quote applies to original collections, not to conversion wrappers. Perhaps the wording ought to be clearer about that.

Comment: Interestingly, [changing](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/es9AlyqfQqG917tPDAR8TA) the former case to a `List` instead of `ListBuffer` passes the assertion, so it seems we get even the original wrapper back.

Comment: That puzzles me that `List` would be different. I'll investigate and report back. (I might not get to it until Tuesday.)

Comment: Ah, the `CollectionConverters` docs state that some conversions are one-way. `scala.collection.immutable.List` is only covered by a one-way conversion. Again, it seems to me that the sentence you quote ("In all cases...") could be improved to be clearer about what cases it applies to. We cannot expect it to apply to one-way conversions.